# PSTricks animation not scaling correctly

Tags: pstricks, animate

Consider the following animation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% LaTeX 3 syntax
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\sundial#1{%
% constants
\def\length{16 }
\def\north{#1 }
% helping constants
\def\northB{\calc{90-\north}}
\def\lengthB{\calc{\length*sin(\northB*pi/180)}}
\def\lengthC{\calc{\length*sin(\north* pi/180)}}
\def\coorx{\calc{\lengthB*sin(\northB*pi/180)}}
\def\coory{\calc{\lengthC*cos(\north* pi/180)}}
\def\maxxA{\calc{\length+0.45}}
\def\maxxB{\calc{1/4*\length*(sin(2*\north*pi/180)+cos(2*\north*pi/180)+3)}}
\def\maxx{\calc{max(\maxxA,\maxxB)}}
\def\maxyA{\calc{1/2*\lengthC*(sin(\north*pi/180)+cos(\north*pi/180))}}
\def\maxyB{\calc{\coory+0.6}}
\def\maxy{\calc{max(\maxyA,\maxyB)}}
% settings
\psset{unit=0.8}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1}
% picture
\fbox{%
\begin{pspicture}(-0.6,-0.15)(\maxx,\maxy)
  \pnodes{P}(0,0)(\coorx,\coory)(\length,0)
  \pspolygon(P0)(P1)(P2)
  \pstMarkAngle{P2}{P0}{P1}{\SI{\north}{\degree}}
  \pstRightAngle{P0}{P1}{P2}
  \pstMarkAngle{P1}{P2}{P0}{\SI{\northB}{\degree}}
  \uput[180](P0){$A$}
  \uput[90](P1){$C$}
  \uput[0](P2){$B$}
  \pstMediatorAB[
    PointSymbol=none,
    PointNameA=none,
    PointNameB=none,
    CodeFig=true,
    CodeFigColor=black
  ]{P1}{P2}{M}{MN}
  \psset{offset=-9pt,linestyle=none,nrot=:U}
  \pcline(P0)(P1)
  \ncput*{\SI{\lengthB}{\cm}}
  \pcline(P1)(P2)
  \ncput*{\SI{\lengthC}{\cm}}
  \pcline[offset=9pt](P0)(P2)
  \ncput*{\SI{\length}{\cm}}
\end{pspicture}%
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls,palindrome]{5}
  \multiframe{51}{iA=20+1}{\sundial{\iA}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

(Note: The `\fbox` is only there to illustrate the size of the `pspicture` frame.)

When I run the animation (from Adobe Reader), the width and the height of the frame doesn't change; instead, the figure gets stretched. How do I fix this?

P.S. When I don't have an animation and choose single (different) values of `\north`, the frame gets ajusted as I would expect.

**Update**

I ended up using the following but [AlexG's method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133918/15874) is better (since the calculations are done automatically):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% LaTeX 3 syntax
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

% helping constants
\def\northB{\calc{90-\north}}
\def\lengthB{\calc{\length*sin(\northB*pi/180)}}
\def\lengthC{\calc{\length*sin(\north* pi/180)}}
\def\coorx{\calc{\lengthB*sin(\northB*pi/180)}}
\def\coory{\calc{\lengthC*cos(\north* pi/180)}}
\def\maxx{\calc{(3+2^(1/2))/4*\length-0.2}}% <-- global maximum for the width (minus adjustment)
\def\maxy{\calc{(1+2^(1/2))/4*\length}}%     <-- global maximum for the height

% settings
\psset{unit=0.8}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1}

% sundial
\def\sundial#1{%
% constants
\def\length{16}
\def\north{#1}
% picture
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.15)(\maxx,\maxy)
  \pnodes{P}(0,0)(\coorx,\coory)(\length,0)
  \pspolygon(P0)(P1)(P2)
  \pstMarkAngle{P2}{P0}{P1}{\small\SI{\north}{\degree}}
  \pstRightAngle{P0}{P1}{P2}
  \pstMarkAngle{P1}{P2}{P0}{\small\SI{\northB}{\degree}}
  \uput[180](P0){$A$}
  \uput[90](P1){$C$}
  \uput[0](P2){$B$}
  \pstMediatorAB[
    PointSymbol=none,
    PointNameA=none,
    PointNameB=none,
    CodeFig=true,
    CodeFigColor=black
  ]{P1}{P2}{M}{MN}
  \psset{offset=-9pt,linestyle=none,nrot=:U}
  \pcline(P0)(P1)
  \ncput*{\SI{\lengthB}{\cm}}
  \pcline(P1)(P2)
  \ncput*{\SI{\lengthC}{\cm}}
  \pcline[offset=9pt](P0)(P2)
  \ncput*{\SI{\length}{\cm}}
\end{pspicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls,palindrome]{5}
  \multiframe{61}{iA=15+1}{\sundial{\iA}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All frames of an animation must have the same size. The first frame determines the animation widget dimensions. The following frames are anamorphically scaled to this size. Thus, if pspicture dimensions are dynamical, all frames except the first one may be stretched or shrinked.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% LaTeX 3 syntax
\ExplSyntaxOn 
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

% constants
\def\length{16 }
% helper macros
\def\northB{\calc{90-\north}}
\def\lengthB{\calc{\length*sin(\northB*pi/180)}}
\def\lengthC{\calc{\length*sin(\north* pi/180)}}
\def\coorx{\calc{\lengthB*sin(\northB*pi/180)}}
\def\coory{\calc{\lengthC*cos(\north* pi/180)}}

%parameterized pspicture
\def\sundial#1{%
  \def\north{#1 }
  % settings
  \psset{unit=0.8}
  \sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1}
  % picture
  \fbox{\begin{pspicture}(-0.6,-0.15)(\maxx,\maxy)
    \pnodes{P}(0,0)(\coorx,\coory)(\length,0)
    \pspolygon(P0)(P1)(P2) 
    \pstMarkAngle{P2}{P0}{P1}{\SI{\north}{\degree}}
    \pstRightAngle{P0}{P1}{P2}
    \pstMarkAngle{P1}{P2}{P0}{\SI{\northB}{\degree}}
    \uput[180](P0){$A$}
    \uput[90](P1){$C$}
    \uput[0](P2){$B$} 
    \pstMediatorAB[
      PointSymbol=none,
      PointNameA=none,
      PointNameB=none,
      CodeFig=true,
      CodeFigColor=black
    ]{P1}{P2}{M}{MN}
    \psset{offset=-9pt,linestyle=none,nrot=:U}
    \pcline(P0)(P1)
    \ncput*{\SI{\lengthB}{\cm}}
    \pcline(P1)(P2)
    \ncput*{\SI{\lengthC}{\cm}}
    \pcline[offset=9pt](P0)(P2)
    \ncput*{\SI{\length}{\cm}}
  \end{pspicture}}%
}   

%find max pspicture dims
\def\maxx{0}\def\maxy{0}
\multido{\iA=20+1}{51}{
  \def\north{\iA }
  \def\maxxA{\calc{\length+0.45}}
  \def\maxxB{\calc{1/4*\length*(sin(2*\north*pi/180)+cos(2*\north*pi/180)+3)}}
  \xdef\maxx{\calc{max(\maxx,\maxxA,\maxxB)}}
  \def\maxyA{\calc{1/2*\lengthC*(sin(\north*pi/180)+cos(\north*pi/180))}}
  \def\maxyB{\calc{\coory+0.6}}
  \xdef\maxy{\calc{max(\maxy,\maxyA,\maxyB)}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls,palindrome]{5}
  \multiframe{51}{iA=20+1}{\sundial{\iA}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Smart method! I ended up doing something similar, except that I calculated the maxiumum of `\maxx` and `\maxy` manually. (See my updated question.)

Comment: Ah, I see. Higher mathematics ;-). As you, I tidied up my code, moving locally and doubly defined macros out of `\sundial` and `\multido`.